# Number of Facebook likes inconsistent

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I just started implementing Facebook likes on my site. I set it up quickly by adding the javascript and the open graph meta-tags. So far it's working fine, but I'm running into an issue.

On this page (the correct URL), the number of Facebook likes is displaying correctly (7 likes):

http://www.quoteso.me/quotes/150375

But when I go onto my Facebook account and click on the liked item (Michelle likes "Change will not come if...") to return to the page, the URL becomes this long jumble:

http://www.quoteso.me/quotes/150375?fb_action_ids=3916984578168&fb_action_types=og.likes&fb_source=other_multiline&action_object_map=%7B%223916984578168%22%3A435713013167457%7D&action_type_map=%7B%223916984578168%22%3A%22og.likes%22%7D&action_ref_map=%5B%5D

And the number of likes changes (1 like).

Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with Facebook open graph at all. Does anybody know why this is happening? How would I go about fixing it?

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The additional parameters are used for analytics (https://www.facebook.com/insights/), e.g. tracking which area of Facebook the user clicked from.

`fb_source=other_multiline`

> The can be found when a user is brought to your app through an open graph multi-line story. Currently this fb_source param can be found in stories on timeline, ticker and newsfeed.

[image: other_multiline]

So in your case (I believe) 7 likes came direct, 1 came from a Facebook Graph Story

Process the data internally if you like, you can even redirect if you want to, but there is no need.

Just ensure that you change this

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.quoteso.me/quotes/150375?fb_action_ids=3916984578168&amp;fb_action_types=og.likes&amp;fb_source=other_multiline&amp;action_object_map=%7B%223916984578168%22%3A435713013167457%7D&amp;action_type_map=%7B%223916984578168%22%3A%22og.likes%22%7D&amp;action_ref_map=%5B%5D" />
```

to the canonical which would be

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.quoteso.me/quotes/150375" />
```

and you explicitly define `href` here

```
 <div class="fb-like inline-block" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="100" data-show-faces="false"></div>
```

so it doesn't grab the current page with all the parameters

- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/fb_source/